# Hyperlink not working in RDLC Report text Box Property's Action :Go to URL

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I have Visual Studio 2013 with update 4.And I am trying to get URL for particular Text Box in the Browser.It is very easy to set up hyperlink for text box in RDLC report.It is the Microsoft post as below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157159.aspx

I applied 6 steps as mentioned in above link,but Still i can't get hyperlink in RDLC report for particular Text Box.I also added EnableHyperlinks="true" in aspx and aspx.cs page too.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try as below in aspx.cs, it works for me

```
   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = True;
```

If it doesn't work, varify it doesn't create relative path issues. Try using System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to create the absolute URL to required URL.

Even if it does not work, please share any error you are getting in report.

Comment: I already added  [ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = True;] in code but it is not working and by setting up the property of text box Action,it is not giving me any error but it is not creating any click event on this text box too.I just applied few steps like this.First: Right click the text box in RDLC file Second: Added Go to URL and added URL="http://localhost:57118/Reports/rptJobSummaryAccruedByActivity_Detail.aspx"

Comment: I solved this issue.The problem was with Rectangle in which i put the text box.Some how Text box property like go to URL or Go To Report is not working, after i remove Rectangle Its working fine as i want.So now this question is closed.Thanks all.